# qgis projections from Michigan's CGI data

Tags: qgis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reproject from Michigan Georef to WGS84 in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18833/how-to-reproject-from-michigan-georef-to-wgs84-in-qgis)

I'm importing shapefiles into QGIS.  These files were created by the state of Michigan, primarily to be used in ArcGIS.  However, when opened in QGIS, the data is projected into the middle of the ocean or on some weird spot on Earth. I've changed the projection running in QGIS to the state plane system, to UTM zone 16, on the layer file, on the project, and even downloaded other counties for state and nothing seems to work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the .prj file that is associated with the shapefiles?

Comment: Yes I do.  Is there anyway of importing that projection file? It doesn't seem to be automatically linking to that projection file as it might in ArcGIS.

Comment: Can you provide a link to a sample shapefile?

Comment: Yes.. Here is the [link](http://www.mcgi.state.mi.us/mgdl/framework/St_Joseph_frwk.zip)

Comment: I investigated a bit and found that cs2cs does the transformation correct, but ogr2ogr (and Qgis) does not. I opened a ticket for that: http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/4910. As a workaround, loading the shapes in uDig and exporting them into EPSG:4326 make them working in Qgis.